# Native libraries in apk aren't being put anywhere on phone

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an app that uses a "native library" (an executable with a .so filename so Android will put it in the correct spot), but it isn't being placed into the nativeLibraryDir given by getApplicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir (/data/app-lib/com...) or anywhere else on the phone. The location of the file inside the apk is /lib/armeabi/hello.so . The file was was packaged into the apk by placing it in app/src/main/jniLibs. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I'm using Gradle with Android Studio 0.8.4

Comment: Might want to mention what build tool you're using.

Comment: Short answer: no, it belongs in the apk.

Comment: It is in the apk. The issue is that it's not being put on the phone when the app is installed.

Comment: First "hello.so" is a non-standard name, which will require you to use System.load() with a full pathname. Normally you would want it to be "libhello.so" so that you could use System.loadLibrary("hello") and let the system find the matching file.  Next, how are you determining that the file is not there?

Comment: I have my app print out nativeLibraryDir. When I go there using a root file explorer, nothing is in the folder. The file does run on my phone when I use run it with adb shell, so I don't think that the architecture is the problem.

Comment: I just tried renaming it libhello.so and using system.loadLibrary("hello"), but it fails because it can't open the file /data/app-lib/com.../libhello.so (because it doesn't exist).

Comment: Try merging the ndk sample hello-jni into your project and see if the library from that gets deployed as expected.  You appear to be trying to game the system by tricking Android into deploying your executable as a library (when it isn't) so maybe that is causing a problem. It will be interesting to see if the genuine jni library from hello-jni works properly.